# How to configure spring boot to validate JWT token with call instropection endpoint of authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have simple resource server application with spring boot, this is yaml file:

```
server: 
  port: 8081
  servlet: 
    context-path: /resource-server-jwt

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/rasool
```

Now, i want to make change in configuration or code to force spring security to validate JWT token with calling introspection endpoint of authorization server instead of local validation with keys, but i didn't find any way as [spring security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can introspect a JWT

Resource server "opaque" token configuratlon means that it won't try to interpret the token by himself, not that the token has to be a UUID or in any specific format.

Spring-boot [`spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.*`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) configuration properties are for JWT decoder. **With this configuration, access tokens must be JWT**.

For token **introspection**, use [`spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque-token.*`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html) properties instead. **With this configuration, access tokens can be in whatever format, including JWT**. "Opaque" means that tokens are considered a "black-box" by resource-server which delegates validataion and attributes retrieval to authorization-server on introspection endpoint:

```yaml
server: 
  port: 8081
  servlet: 
    context-path: /resource-server-jwt

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        opaque-token:
          introspection-uri: http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/rasool/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
          client-id: change-me
          client-secret: change-me
```

Introspection uri from [`.well-known/openid-configuration`](http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/rasool/.well-known/openid-configuration)

If you are using Java configurationn the switch is about the same: replace `http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()...` with `http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken()...`

### Complete working sample [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_introspection)

It does a few things useful for resource-servers:

- authorities mapping (choose attributes to parse user authorities from, prefix & case processing)
- CORS configuration
- stateless-session management
- CSRF with Cookie repo
- anonymous enabled for a list of configured public routes
- 401 (unauthorized) instead of 302 (redirect to login) when trying to access protected resources with missing or invalid Authorization

Comment: I know I can change the security configuration to use opaque tokens, but i don't want to do this. my main problem is that I want to limit access tokens count for each user, I mean I want them to use only one active token and make older tokens invalid when user logs in, so I need to make resource servers call introspection endpoint for validating token because I implemented this mechanism In authorization server by storing the older tokens in authorization server in blocklist in Redis.

Comment: what do you mean that saying "You can introspect JWTs with it", I checked your example, you used from opaque token instead of JWT, but I want to this with JWT, are you mean that this is the wrong approach? could you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73288240/how-limit-access-tokens-count-for-each-user-in-keycloak

Comment: just send JWTs to introspection endpoint, it works. As I wrote, configuration property would be better named `introspected-token` rather than `opaque-token`. I don't know how to be more clear, just try with the conf in the answer.

Comment: but the spring security doesn't do this, Do you mean to do this manually for example with a web filter or something like this?

Comment: Spring-security does this. There is even a chapter about that in the doc I linked: [Using Introspection with JWTs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-opaque-jwt-introspector). Just try the solution above (and RTFM).

Comment: Introspection has nothing to do with the token format, it is just a flow in which resource-server submits a token to an authorization-server for validation. The token can be opaque, a JWT or absolutely whatever introspection endpoint accepts.