# How limit access tokens count for each user in keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

I am using Keyclaok as an authorization server and implemented resource servers with spring boot. Now I want to limit the active JWT token count for each user. so after I googled this issue, I find that I should use this mechanism, when the user logs into the system if the user has an older token, that token would be stored in the blacklist, and then in each request that the user made to the resource server, validate token with calling introspection endpoint of Keyclaok and then check that given token is in the blacklist or not.

But I find that spring security does not call the introspection endpoint to validate the JWT token and uses local validation instead.

What is the best approach to implement this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

There can be good reasons for a user to have simultaneous tokens: in SingleSignOn scenarios, you can authenticate on the same authorization-server with various clients. You'll get a token per client.

I would just reduce tokens life-span. Wouldn't access-tokens expiring after 30s solve your concern?

JWT access-token should be quite short lived and serious client libs handle silent access-tokens renewal.

On keycloak, this is tuned in "advanced settings" for each client.